# How to implement Azure AD authentication for a web app developed in Django which is running in a Infrastructure as a service (IaaS)?

Tags: django, azure-active-directory, iaas

There is a web application developed in Django which is running in IAAS server. How can we implement Azure AD in that web application?
i.e when some clicks the web app link it should authenticate using Azure AD of a company.

Comment: https://github.com/datawiza-inc/msgraph-training-pythondjangoapp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [django-microsoft-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-microsoft-auth/) and [django-azure-ad-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-azure-ad-auth/) projects and documentation. Alternatively, to the [Azure Identity client library for Python.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python)